# How can I extract this datafram to csv file?

Tags: csv

I am trying to extract youtube subtitles to a CSV file(or txt).
I succeeded to drop out the index number and leave the only text in the y column.
However, I am wandering to extract contents to CSV file(or txt).
What code should I type in the last line?

```
subtitle_out=subtitle.set_index('y')
subtitle_out

subtitle_out_df = pd.DataFrame(subtitle_out)
subtitle_out_df
```

[image]

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the to_csv() (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method like the following:

```
subtitle_out_df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 
By the way, what's the difference between `subtitle_out_df.to_csv('filename.csv')` and
`subtitle_out_df.to_csv('filename.csv', index=True)` ?

Comment: No difference, because the default value of index is True :)